# Windows 7 Long Delay on Login or Unlock

Tags: windows-7, uac

I have a clean install of Windows 7 x32 running on my HP DV6449us and am experiencing a really long delay (10+ seconds) when unlocking or logging into my computer. The same issue was happening with UAC but I was able to turn that off. I realize this is a security risk but couldn't take it any more.  I've read about this being video driver related but have updated the drivers to the newest I could find for the GeForce Go 6150.

Anyone else experiencing this? My desktop is very happy but he's sporting a Nvidia 260 GT. Is it just the lack of firepower?

Comment: This is still unresolved. Anyone?

Comment: I also have the very same issue, and it takes 30 or more seconds to ublock - black screen, then screen appears but is frozen, then i can use it. HP NX6310 with integrated video card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling the 'Aero' theme and use the Windows 7 Basic layout.

Comment: Funny or not, but when i switched to Windows 7 Basic theme, i was lagging non-stop, the whole desktop environment had a delay. So i switched back to aero, then it will lag just when i lock my computer or at UAC prompt :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the background to a solid color. I had the same problem and this solved it as weird and annoying a fix as it is. Let us know if it works. I also had an adequate video card.

Comment: Didn't work for me (note i`m not the one who asked the question)